# My Navigation bar is going under my backgroud image when Iam veiwing it in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<header class="header">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Genius High School</title>
  
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="academics.html" class="nav-link">Academics</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="worksheets.html" class="nav-link">Worksheets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="circulars.html" class="nav-link">Circulars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="message.html" class="nav-link">Message</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="big-image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1><img src="imageedit_2_7258851370.gif">  Genius High School</h1>
          <br>
        </span>
        <p>Learn to serve</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
      <div id="news">
       <center><h1>School News</h1><center>
       <br>
       <br>
       <img src="png_20211127_162818_0000.png" class="news">
       <br>
       <h2>10th class student represented football tournament at state level(maharashtra).
         <center>Runner-up trophy<center>
       </h2>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer">
        <br>
        <h1><img src="imageedit_2_7258851370.gif">  Genius High School</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="links">
          <h1><i class="fas fa-link"></i>  Links</h1>
          <ul class="navtwo">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
            <li><a href="worksheets.html">Worksheets</a></li>
            <li><a href="circulars.html">Circulars</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="message.html">Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <br>
            <br>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tel">
          <br><br>
          <h1><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>  Get in touch</h1>
          <br>
          <a class="phone_number" href="tel:+91-934-638-8595">+91-934-638-8595</a>
        <br>
          <a class="phone_number" href="tel:+91-970-026-0200">+91-934-638-8595</a>
        <br>
        <a class="phone_number" href="email:geints2013@gmail.com">geints2013@gmail.com</a>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </footer>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,500;1,400&display=swap');
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
      font-weight: 800;
}

.big-image {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image:url(school.jpg);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay img {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
}

.overlay h1 {
  font-size: 85px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.overlay p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px;
}

#news h1 {
  color: navy;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

#news a:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.news {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}  

.navtwo {
  color: yellow;
  list-style-type: none;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(139, 218, 255);
  color: rgb(139, 139, 0);
}

footer img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

ul li {
  color: rgb(109, 109, 0);
  font-size: large;
}

li a {
  color: #646600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.links{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tel {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tel a {
  color: #686900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E8F0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  overflow: auto;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 5rem;
}

.nav-link{
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #475569;
}

.nav-link:hover{
  color: #482ff7;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #482ff7;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-menu {
      position: fixed;
      left: -100%;
      top: 5rem;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      transition: 0.3s;
      box-shadow:
          0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
      left: 0;
  }

  .nav-item {
      margin: 2.5rem 0;
  }

  .hamburger {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

function mobileMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}

const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));

function closeMenu() {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}
```

When I am viewing this on mobile the navigation bar items are going under the background image.
I've tried changing many things in it but still, it's not working. I changed the margin of the navbar but it was not working. Plz tell me if something is wrong in the code also plz tell it in detail

Comment: Just noticed the navigation bar is in the header instead of the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this on your editor :

and add CSS

```
.nav-menu {
  z-index:999;
}
```

```js
    const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
    const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

    hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

    function mobileMenu() {
        hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
        navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    }

    const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

    navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", closeMenu));

    function closeMenu() {
        hamburger.classList.remove("active");
        navMenu.classList.remove("active");
    }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,500;1,400&display=swap');
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
      font-weight: 800;
}

.big-image {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image:url(school.jpg);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay img {
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
}

.overlay h1 {
  font-size: 85px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.overlay p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

#news {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px;
}

#news h1 {
  color: navy;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

#news a:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.news {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}  

.navtwo {
  color: yellow;
  list-style-type: none;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(139, 218, 255);
  color: rgb(139, 139, 0);
}

footer img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

ul li {
  color: rgb(109, 109, 0);
  font-size: large;
}

li a {
  color: #646600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.links{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tel {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tel a {
  color: #686900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E8F0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  overflow: auto;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index:999;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 5rem;
}

.nav-link{
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #475569;
}

.nav-link:hover{
  color: #482ff7;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #482ff7;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav-menu {
      position: fixed;
      left: -100%;
      top: 5rem;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      transition: 0.3s;
      box-shadow:
          0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
      left: 0;
  }

  .nav-item {
      margin: 2.5rem 0;
  }

  .hamburger {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Genius High School</title>
</head>
<header class="header">
  
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="academics.html" class="nav-link">Academics</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="worksheets.html" class="nav-link">Worksheets</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="circulars.html" class="nav-link">Circulars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="message.html" class="nav-link">Message</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="big-image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <span>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1><img src="imageedit_2_7258851370.gif">  Genius High School</h1>
          <br>
        </span>
        <p>Learn to serve</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
      <div id="news">
       <center><h1>School News</h1><center>
       <br>
       <br>
       <img src="png_20211127_162818_0000.png" class="news">
       <br>
       <h2>10th class student represented football tournament at state level(maharashtra).
         <center>Runner-up trophy<center>
       </h2>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer">
        <br>
        <h1><img src="imageedit_2_7258851370.gif">  Genius High School</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="links">
          <h1><i class="fas fa-link"></i>  Links</h1>
          <ul class="navtwo">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="academics.html">Academics</a></li>
            <li><a href="worksheets.html">Worksheets</a></li>
            <li><a href="circulars.html">Circulars</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="message.html">Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <br>
            <br>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tel">
          <br><br>
          <h1><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>  Get in touch</h1>
          <br>
          <a class="phone_number" href="tel:+91-934-638-8595">+91-934-638-8595</a>
        <br>
          <a class="phone_number" href="tel:+91-970-026-0200">+91-934-638-8595</a>
        <br>
        <a class="phone_number" href="email:geints2013@gmail.com">geints2013@gmail.com</a>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br>
        </div>
      </footer>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a `head` with a `header`.

The `head` of an html document contains metadata and goes before the body.

A `header` contains html elements that belong at the top of the body. (Inside the body)

So in short, your code is missing a `head` and you seem to have placed your `header` outside the body, where the `head` should be.

Here's a sample boilerplate:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    // title, metadata, etc.
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        ...
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```